# Creating a measure to calculate by criteria and by day with different tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables as shown below. One with my production data the other one with my maintenance data (basically how long the equipment remain out of work).

Production:
[image: Production]

Maintenance:
[image: Maintenance]

I don't want to create another table to calculate it because I actually work with 3 year long data, hundreds of equipment and a production table with even more lines per equipment per day.

My first goal was to calculate how fast my equipment should produce (PlannedProductionQtt / PlannedProductionTime). A measure here is relatively simple and works fine to plot some charts organized by month or days. Let's call this measure "Measure1"

The real problem was when I tried to calculate the impact of the StoppedTime. It basically would be my StoppedTime times Measure1. Here I have a problem doing it daily because PowerBI sums all the PlannedProductionQtt, divides it by all the PlannedProductionTime and the multiplies it by my StoppedTime. Which gives me a false value.

Below there is a table with the false results I get now and the results I wish to obtain.

Table Correct vs. Wrong:

[image: Table correct vs wrong]

So far I am working with `Result = Calculate(SUM(PlannedProductionQtt)/Sum(PlannedProductionTime)*Sum(DecProdTime))`
I feel that if I can put a "dynamic" filter in this calculation it would understand not to mix different equipments for the sum, maybe?

Comment: Can you show us what values you are expected per day, for the tables above?

Comment: Of course, sorry for the delay. I edited it at the end of my post.